# Set Hive TBLPROPERTIES using (py)Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I need to set a custom property in one of my Hive tables using pySpark.
Normally, I would just run this command in any Hive interface to do it:

`ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ('key1'='value1');`

But the question is, can I accomplish the same within a pySpark script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was actually easy... it can be set using sqlContext in pySpark:

`sqlContext.sql("ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES('key1' = 'value1')")`

It will return an empty DataFrame: `DataFrame[]`
But the property is actually present on the target table. It can be similarly retrieved using:

`sqlContext.sql("SHOW TBLPROPERTIES table_name('key1')").collect()[0].asDict()`

`{'value': u'value1'}`